# sweetalert2 Success and Error Alerts :: Only Showing Error Alerts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sweetalert2

I am having some trouble getting the sweetalert2 alerts to switch between successful operation alerts and errors. It is currently only showing the error alerts.

I am not quite sure where I am going wrong. My code is as follows:

**- carsEdit.js**

```
// Imported react libraries and hooks.
import React, { useState } from "react";
// Requiring Axios.
import axios from "axios";
// Imported components from React Bootstrap.
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
} from "react-bootstrap";
// Imported icons from FontAwesome.
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlus, faEdit, faTrashAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
// Imported Swal from sweetalert2.
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

/**
 * @param {*} cars
 * @param {*} setCars
 * Created a search component with an input area, dropdown menu for the categories and a search button.
 * Set the initial states of the prop values using the useState() hook.
 */

const CarEdit = ({ cars, setCars }) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [Model, setModel] = useState("");
  const [Make, setMake] = useState("");
  const [Owner, setOwner] = useState("");
  const [Registration, setRegistration] = useState("");
  const [Address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [previousOwners, setPreviousOwners] = useState("");

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the create function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/api/create. Utilizing the Post method and added a header to set the content type to JSON.
   * Added the necessary props to alocate values to and stringified the content to be added to the JSON file.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error. An error will occur if all the information is not
   * entered as set in the backend/ server side and the content will be returned unchanged.
   * @param {*} e Posting content to JSON as a string and returning the content as objects to the UI.
   */

  const create = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("cars/create", {
        Model,
        Make,
        Owner,
        Registration,
        Address,
        previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
        });
        setCars(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: "User data missing",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the update function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/api/update/ (an ID should be entered to update that specific car). Utilizing the
   * Put method and added a header to set the content type to JSON.
   * Added the necessary props to alocate values to and stringified the content to be added to the JSON file.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error. An error will occur if all the information is not
   * entered as set in the backend/ server side and the content will be returned unchanged.
   * @param {*} e Updating content, that exists in the JSON file, as a string and returning the content as objects to the UI.
   */

  const updateOne = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .put(`cars/updateOne/${id}`, {
        Model: Model,
        Make: Make,
        Owner: Owner,
        Registration: Registration,
        Address: Address,
        previousOwners: previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
        });
        setCars(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: "User data missing",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the update function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/api/update/ (an ID should be entered to update that specific car). Utilizing the
   * Put method and added a header to set the content type to JSON.
   * Added the necessary props to alocate values to and stringified the content to be added to the JSON file.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error. An error will occur if all the information is not
   * entered as set in the backend/ server side and the content will be returned unchanged.
   * @param {*} e Updating content, that exists in the JSON file, as a string and returning the content as objects to the UI.
   */

  const updateMany = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .put(`cars/updateMany/${Model}`, {
        Make: Make,
        Owner: Owner,
        Registration: Registration,
        Address: Address,
        previousOwners: previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
        });
        setCars(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: "User data missing",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the delete function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/api/delete/ (an ID should be entered to update that specific car). Utilizing the
   * Delete method and added a header to set the content type to JSON.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be removed from the JSON file and UI.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error.
   * @param {*} e Deleting content that exists in the JSON file.
   */

  const remove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .delete(`cars/delete/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data === "Applied successfully")
          Swal.fire({
            imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
            imageWidth: 150,
            imageHeight: 150,
            imageAlt: "Success",
            confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
            width: 400,
            title: "SUCCESS!",
          });
        setCars(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Added the handleChange() function to the onChange() event to set the new values of the props when values are entered into the input
   * elements.
   * Created buttons for the cars app. Passed onClick() events to create, update and delete cars.
   * @returns Form with labels, input and button elements that can be used to add, update and delete cars.
   */

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Form className="d-flex flex-column">
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="id">ID:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="id"
              value={id}
              onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="model">Model:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="model"
              value={Model || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setModel(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="make">Make:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="make"
              value={Make || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setMake(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="owner">Owner:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="owner"
              value={Owner || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setOwner(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="registration">Registration:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="registration"
              value={Registration || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setRegistration(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="address">Address:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="address"
              value={Address || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="previousOwners">Previous Owners:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="previousOwners"
              value={previousOwners || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setPreviousOwners(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Add New Car"
              onClick={(e) => create(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
              Add
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Update a Car"
              onClick={(e) => updateOne(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
              <span id="editone">x1</span> Update
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Update Many Cars"
              onClick={(e) => updateMany(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
              <span id="editmany">+</span> Update
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Delete a Car"
              onClick={(e) => remove(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} />
              Delete
            </Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exported CarEdit to App.js.
export default CarEdit;
```

- carsController.js

```
// Requiring the schemas that has been created in the carsModel.js file.
const Car = require("../models/carsModel.js");
// Requiring Mongoose.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/**
 * POST/ CREATE:
 * @required  Body properties: Model, Make, Owner, Registration, and the Address
 * @param {*} req Creating a new post with the property.
 * @param {*} res Updated copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns List of cars and a confirmation message is returned to confirm that the post has been created or an error message should the
 * request be unsuccessful.
 */

exports.createController = (req, res) => {
  let car = new Car({
    Model: req.body.Model,
    Make: req.body.Make,
    Owner: req.body.Owner,
    Registration: req.body.Registration,
    Address: req.body.Address,
    previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
  });
  car
    .save()
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error creating the car." + err));
};

/**
 * GET/ READ:
 * @required  Content.
 * @param {*} req Getting the array of cars.
 * @param {*} res Copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns A list of the current cars that are already written.
 */

// Requesting all the cars' information from MongoDB and retuning the response with the information.
exports.getAllController = (req, res) => {
  Car.find()
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) =>
      res.status(400).json("Error getting the cars' information." + err)
    );
};

// Requesting all the cars' information from MongoDB and retuning the response with the information.
exports.getOlderCars = (req, res) => {
  Car.find({ Model: { $lt: 2016 } })
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) =>
      res.status(400).json("Error getting the cars' information." + err)
    );
};

/**
 * PUT/ UPDATE:
 * @required Body properties: id.
 * @param {*} req Post with the matching id to be returned and updated with the new post.
 * @param {*} res Updated copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns List of cars and a confirmation message is returned to confirm that the post has been updatedor an error message should the request
 * be unsuccessful.
 */

// Fetching the information of one car by id for updating. Using $set to set the information for the relevant car with the matching id.
exports.updateOneController = (req, res) => {
  Car.findOneAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $set: {
        Model: req.body.Model,
        Make: req.body.Make,
        Owner: req.body.Owner,
        Registration: req.body.Registration,
        Address: req.body.Address,
        previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error updating the car." + err));
};

// Allowing a user to update more than one car, using the model year of the car. Using $set to set the information for the relevant cars with
// the matching model years.
exports.updateManyController = (req, res) => {
  Car.updateMany(
    {
      Model: req.params.Model,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        Make: req.body.Make,
        Owner: req.body.Owner,
        Registration: req.body.Registration,
        Address: req.body.Address,
        previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
      },
    }
  )
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error updating the car." + err));
};

/**
 * DELETE:
 * @required  Body properties: id.
 * @param {*} req Post with the matching id to be deleted.
 * @param {*} res Updated copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns List of cars and a confirmation message is returned to confirm that the post has been deleted or an error message should the
 * request be unsuccessful.
 */

// Fetching the information of one car by id for deletion.
exports.removeOneController = (req, res) => {
  Car.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json({message: "Error deleting the car." + err}));
};
```

I have also pushed the complete application's code to GitHub: https://github.com/ChanBos/Car-Database-App

I would appreciate any assistance that anyone is willing to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution for this after further research.

I have altered the code as follows:

**- carsEdit.js**

```
// Imported react libraries and hooks.
import React, { useState } from "react";
// Requiring Axios.
import axios from "axios";
// Imported components from React Bootstrap.
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
} from "react-bootstrap";
// Imported icons from FontAwesome.
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlus, faEdit, faTrashAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
// Imported Swal from sweetalert2.
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

/**
 * Set the initial states of the prop values using the useState() hook.
 * @param {*} cars
 * @param {*} setCars
 */

/**
 * Used the useState() hook to set the initial values of the props.
 * @returns The initial states of the prop values.
 */

const CarEdit = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [Model, setModel] = useState("");
  const [Make, setMake] = useState("");
  const [Owner, setOwner] = useState("");
  const [Registration, setRegistration] = useState("");
  const [Address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [previousOwners, setPreviousOwners] = useState("");

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the create function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/cars/create. Utilizing the Post method.
   * Added the necessary props to alocate values to be written to the database.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error.
   * @param {*} e Posting content to the database and returning the content as objects to the UI.
   */

  const create = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("cars/create", {
        Model,
        Make,
        Owner,
        Registration,
        Address,
        previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
          text: response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: error,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the update function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/cars/updateOne/:id. Utilizing the Put method.
   * Added the necessary props to alocate values to be written to the database.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error.
   * @param {*} e Updating content of one car, that exists in the database, and returning the content as objects to the UI via the modal year.
   */

  const updateOne = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .put(`cars/updateOne/${id}`, {
        Model: Model,
        Make: Make,
        Owner: Owner,
        Registration: Registration,
        Address: Address,
        previousOwners: previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
          text: response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: error.response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the update function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/cars/updateMany/:id. Utilizing the Put method.
   * Added the necessary props to alocate values to be written to the database.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error.
   * @param {*} e Updating content of one car, that exists in the database, and returning the content as objects to the UI via the model year.
   */

  const updateMany = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .put(`cars/updateMany/${Model}`, {
        Make: Make,
        Owner: Owner,
        Registration: Registration,
        Address: Address,
        previousOwners: previousOwners,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
          text: response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: error.response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Assigned an event.preventDefault() method to ensure that the page is not refreshed once the delete function is executed.
   * Fetching the content from http://localhost:8080/cars/delete/:id. Utilizing the Delete method.
   * Added the necessary props to remove values from the database.
   * If successful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear to confirm success and the content will be added to the UI as objects.
   * If unsuccessful a modal (Sweetalert2 - Swal.fire) will appear displaying an error.
   * @param {*} e Deleting content that exists in the database via id.
   */

  const remove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .delete(`cars/delete/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
          text: response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: error.response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };

  /**
   * Added the props to be set when the onChange() event is triggered to set the new values of the props when values are entered into the input
   * elements.
   * Created buttons for the cars app. Passed onClick() events to create, update and delete cars.
   * @returns Form with labels, input and button elements that can be used to add, update one or many cars and delete cars.
   */

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Form className="d-flex flex-column">
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="id">ID:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="id"
              value={id}
              onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="model">Model:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="model"
              value={Model || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setModel(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="make">Make:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="make"
              value={Make || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setMake(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="owner">Owner:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="owner"
              value={Owner || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setOwner(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="registration">Registration:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="registration"
              value={Registration || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setRegistration(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="address">Address:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="address"
              value={Address || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="previousOwners">Previous Owners:</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="previousOwners"
              value={previousOwners || ""}
              onChange={(e) => setPreviousOwners(e.target.value)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Add New Car"
              onClick={(e) => create(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
              Add
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Update a Car"
              onClick={(e) => updateOne(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
              <span id="editone">x1</span> Update
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Update Many Cars"
              onClick={(e) => updateMany(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
              <span id="editmany">+</span> Update
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="button"
              title="Delete a Car"
              onClick={(e) => remove(e)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} />
              Delete
            </Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exported CarEdit to App.js.
export default CarEdit;
```

**- carsController.js**

```
// Requiring the schemas that has been created in the carsModel.js file.
const Car = require("../models/carsModel.js");
// Requiring Mongoose.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

/**
 * POST/ CREATE:
 * @required  Body properties: Model, Make, Owner, Registration, and the Address
 * @param {*} req Creating a new post with the property.
 * @param {*} res Updated copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns List of cars and a confirmation message is returned to confirm that the post has been created or an error message should the
 * request be unsuccessful.
 */

exports.createController = (req, res) => {
  let car = new Car({
    Model: req.body.Model,
    Make: req.body.Make,
    Owner: req.body.Owner,
    Registration: req.body.Registration,
    Address: req.body.Address,
    previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
  });
  car
    .save()
    .then((cars) => res.json({ message: "Car created successfully.", cars }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error creating the car.", err));
};

/**
 * GET/ READ:
 * @required  Content.
 * @param {*} req Getting the array of cars.
 * @param {*} res Copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns A list of the current cars that are already written.
 */

// Requesting all the cars' information from MongoDB and retuning the response with the information.
exports.getAllController = (req, res) => {
  Car.find()
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) =>
      res.status(400).json("Error getting the cars' information.", err)
    );
};

// Requesting all the cars' information from MongoDB and retuning the response with the information.
exports.getOlderCars = (req, res) => {
  Car.find({ Model: { $lt: 2016 } })
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) =>
      res.status(400).json("Error getting the cars' information.", err)
    );
};

/**
 * PUT/ UPDATE:
 * @required Body properties: id.
 * @param {*} req Post with the matching id to be returned and updated with the new post.
 * @param {*} res Updated copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns List of cars and a confirmation message is returned to confirm that the post has been updatedor an error message should the request
 * be unsuccessful.
 */

// Fetching the information of one car by id for updating. Using $set to set the information for the relevant car with the matching id.
exports.updateOneController = (req, res) => {
  Car.findOneAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $set: {
        Model: req.body.Model,
        Make: req.body.Make,
        Owner: req.body.Owner,
        Registration: req.body.Registration,
        Address: req.body.Address,
        previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then((cars) => res.json({ message: "Car updated successfully.", cars }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error updating the car.", err));
};

// Allowing a user to update more than one car, using the model year of the car. Using $set to set the information for the relevant cars with
// the matching model years.
exports.updateManyController = (req, res) => {
  Car.updateMany(
    {
      Model: req.params.Model,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        Make: req.body.Make,
        Owner: req.body.Owner,
        Registration: req.body.Registration,
        Address: req.body.Address,
        previousOwners: req.body.previousOwners,
      },
    }
  )
    .then((cars) => res.json({ message: "Cars updated successfully.", cars }))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error updating the car.", err));
};

/**
 * DELETE:
 * @required  Body properties: id.
 * @param {*} req Post with the matching id to be deleted.
 * @param {*} res Updated copy of the content (copyContent).
 * @returns List of cars and a confirmation message is returned to confirm that the post has been deleted or an error message should the
 * request be unsuccessful.
 */

// Fetching the information of one car by id for deletion.
exports.removeOneController = (req, res) => {
  Car.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((cars) => res.json({ message: "Car deleted successfully.", cars }))
    .catch((err) =>
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Error deleting the car.", err })
    );
};
```

Instead of this, for instance:

- carEdit.js

```
const remove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .delete(`cars/delete/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200 && response.data === "Applied successfully")
          Swal.fire({
            imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
            imageWidth: 150,
            imageHeight: 150,
            imageAlt: "Success",
            confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
            width: 400,
            title: "SUCCESS!",
          });
        setCars(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };
```

- carController.js

```
exports.removeOneController = (req, res) => {
  Car.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((cars) => res.json(cars))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json({message: "Error deleting the car." + err}));
};
```

...it is supposed to be:

- carEdit.js

```
const remove = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .delete(`cars/delete/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/success.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Success",
          confirmButtonColor: "#007aff",
          width: 400,
          title: "SUCCESS!",
          text: response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          imageUrl: "./images/exclamation.gif",
          imageWidth: 150,
          imageHeight: 150,
          imageAlt: "Error",
          confirmButtonColor: "#ff0000",
          width: 400,
          title: "ERROR!",
          text: error.response.data.message,
        }).then(function () {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });
  };
```

- carController.js

```
exports.removeOneController = (req, res) => {
  Car.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((cars) => res.json({ message: "Car deleted successfully.", cars }))
    .catch((err) =>
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Error deleting the car.", err })
    );
};
```

The changes made was due to Axios handling some of the functionality that has been removed (initially utilized) by default.